# Want to pass dynamic values to another function and then saving it to database

Tags: javascript

I am improving my coding skills.

Ques:-
I have 2 buttons named button1 and button2 and both have onClick function on it.
When button1 is clicked i have 2 values (a, b). so, when button2 is clicked i want to save that values in database. whenever button1 is clicked the a and b values changes. i.e a and b values are dynamic in nature. How to pass that values to database when button2 clicked.

Solution code can be in any language. Just need understanding for above query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask], show effort and research, and create a [mcve] if you're stuck with a specific code.

Comment: Why the `performace` tag? What database? Your question is currently too broad to be answered in this state. Please [edit] it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry my bad. I am new here just opened a account. I'll improve my question asking skills in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set variables with button a, then access them with button b. While you could store the values in document-scope variables, in this example I'll store the values in input tags - that way you can send them to the database either through a form submission or ajax.

```
<form action='yourBackEndScript.php'>
   <input id='val1_holder' name='val1_holder' />
   <input id='val2_holder' name='val2_holder' />
</form>
<script>
    var val1 = 'test1', var2 = 'test2'
    function b1click() {
       // set random variable
       val1 = Math.random() * 1000
       val2 = Math.random() * 10000
       document.getElementById('val1_holder').value = val1
       document.getElementById('val2_holder').value = val2
    }

    function b2click() {
       // access the variables directly: val1, val2 
       // ajax function sends the variables through POST to a backend that writes to the database

       // or submit the form and send the variables to a backend script
       document.forms[0].submit();
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ELs_magicButton = document.querySelectorAll(".magicButton");

const generateButtonValues = () => {
  ELs_magicButton.forEach(EL => {
    const randChar = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.random() * 25);
    EL.value = randChar;
    EL.textContent = randChar;
  })
};

const saveBtnValueToDB = (ev) => {
  const btnVal = ev.currentTarget.value;
  // Save to database 
  console.log(`saving value ${btnVal} to database`);
  // Generate new values
  generateButtonValues();
};


ELs_magicButton.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", saveBtnValueToDB));
generateButtonValues();
```

```html
<button type="button" class="magicButton"></button>
<button type="button" class="magicButton"></button>
```